# Procedural Generation of Feature Columns for use with Sagemaker Tensorflow Instance

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

Have exhausted myself on this one so any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to set up hosting my tensorflow model with Amazon Sagemaker and following the example found [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_iris_dnn_classifier_using_estimators/iris_dnn_classifier.py).

This example uses hard coded feature columns with known dimensionality.

```
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(INPUT_TENSOR_NAME, shape=[4])]
```

I need to avoid this as my dataset changes often.

## Local Machine Set Up

Now on my local machine, I define a list of columns

```
my_feature_columns = []
```

With the following strategy

```
#Define placeholder nodes based on datatype being inserted

for key in train_x.keys():
```

Where train_x is the dataset without labels.

'OBJECTS' become hashed buckets as there are many possible categories

```
    if train_x[key].dtypes == 'object':

        categorical_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(
                key = key,
                hash_bucket_size = len(train_x[key].unique()))

        my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
                categorical_column=categorical_column,
                dimension=5))
```

'INT64' become categorical columns as there are only two possible categories (I have recoded booleans to 0/1)

```
    elif train_x[key].dtypes == 'int64':

        categorical_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity(
                key=key,
                num_buckets=2)

        my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.indicator_column(categorical_column))
```

'FLOATS' become continuous columns

```
    elif train_x[key].dtypes == 'float':
        my_feature_columns.append(
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column(
        key=key))
```

On the local machine this yields a nice list of all of my features that can be given as an argument when instantiating a tf.estimator.DNNClassifier. As more categories are added to each OBJECT column, this is handled by

```
hash_bucket_size = len(train_x[key].unique())
```

## Sagemaker

From the [Docs](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/README.rst#preparing-the-tensorflow-training-script)

*Preparing the TensorFlow training script
Your TensorFlow training script must be a Python 2.7 source file. The SageMaker TensorFlow docker image uses this script by calling specifically-named functions from this script.*

*The training script must contain the following:*

*Exactly one of the following:
model_fn: defines the model that will be trained.
keras_model_fn: defines the tf.keras model that will be trained.
estimator_fn: defines the tf.estimator.Estimator that will train the model.*

*train_input_fn: preprocess and load training data.*

*eval_input_fn: preprocess and load evaluation data.*

Again, from the [example](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_iris_dnn_classifier_using_estimators/iris_dnn_classifier.py)

```
def train_input_fn(training_dir, params):
"""Returns input function that would feed the model during training"""
return _generate_input_fn(training_dir, 'iris_training.csv')
```

This function is called by the sagemaker docker image, which adds its own argument for **training_dir**, it is not a global parameter.

When trying to access my training data from the estimator_fn to build a my_feature_columns list

```
NameError: global name 'training_dir' is not defined
```

## I would love to be able to do something like this.

```
def estimator_fn(run_config, params):

my_feature_columns = []

train_x , _ , _ , _ = datasplitter(os.path.join(training_dir, 'leads_test_frame.csv'))

for key in train_x.keys():
    if train_x[key].dtypes == 'object':

        categorical_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(
                key = key,
                hash_bucket_size = len(train_x[key].unique()))

        my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
                categorical_column=categorical_column,
                dimension=5))

    elif train_x[key].dtypes == 'int64':

        categorical_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity(
                key=key,
                num_buckets=2)

        my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.indicator_column(categorical_column))

    elif train_x[key].dtypes == 'float':
        my_feature_columns.append(
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column(
        key=key))

return tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
                                  hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                  n_classes=2,
                                  config=run_config)
```

Thanks to anyone who can help in any way. Will happily give more info if needed but feel like 4 pages is probably enough :-S

Cheers!
Clem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**training_dir** points to your training channel, i.e. */opt/ml/input/data/training*. You can hardcode this location inside your **estimation_fn**.

When training starts, SageMaker makes the data for the channel available in the */opt/ml/input/data/**channel_name*** directory in the Docker container.

You can find more information here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo.html#your-algorithms-training-algo-running-container.